# Enable dialer autocomplete feature in Android 4.3 on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

My phone was upgraded to 4.3, as I see in the Settings.

How can I enable the dialer autocomplete feature in Android 4.3 on Galaxy Nexus? I don't see any `Dialpad autocomplete` in my [phone app setting](http://officialandroid.blogspot.com/2013/07/introducing-android-43-sweeter-jelly.html).

Comment: Could tou post a screenshot of your call settings?

Answer (score 2):

From [mybookofknowledge](http://www.mybookofknowledge.com/2013/08/enable-dial-pad-auto-complete-in.html):

> 1. Go to your Dial Pad and select the Settings options.
> 2. Under the other call settings, you can see the option `Dial pad autocomplete`.
> 3. Enable this option and now you can see suggestions when you dial a phone number.

[image]

NOTE: Make sure you are using the stock dialer.